# Why toggle doesn't remove class name?

Tags: javascript, toggle

Can someone help me with toggle method? Please see below my code

My problem is that by pressing on image toggle adds class of active, thus adding some CSS properties to it, however by consecutive pressing on the same image it doesn't remove class of active from it.

I cannot remove removeActiveClass function, because it has to go through NodeList and check which one has class of active and remove it, thus adding active only to the image that was clicked.

```js
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

panels.forEach((panel) => {
  panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeActiveClasses();
    panel.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});

function removeActiveClasses() {
  panels.forEach(panel => {
    panel.classList.remove('active');
  });
}
```

**CSS CODE**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
}

.panel {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0.5;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: flex 0.7s ease-in;
}

.panel h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panel.active {
  flex: 5;
}

.panel.active h3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in 0.6s;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .panel:nth-of-type(4),
  .panel:nth-of-type(5) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hello, this is unrelated to your question, but I see that you are adding a new eventListener for each panel. It is much better to instead just add ONE eventListener to your panels (with s), and then check inside the Callback function, which panel got clicked. For a more detailed explanation of what I mean, please watch this 7 minute video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqQZ8SttQsI ;)

Comment: could you not search for a list of items with the "active" class, rather than looping through the panels?

Comment: Your code works exactly as I'd expect it to: https://jsfiddle.net/m9jz8g0L/ (It might not be the best way, but it works!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you just remove the active class from all your panels and then toggle the active class on the current panel so it will always get set to active (as the active class was just removed).  You can try to check to see if the current panel already has the active class and if not then add the class after you call the remove:

```js
panels.forEach((panel) => {
  panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const isActive = panel.classList.contains('active');
    removeActiveClasses();

    if (!isActive) {
      panel.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
});
```